# DialogFlow v2 Error: [ResourceName error] Path '' does not match template

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I have made a couple of functions that help me change the context in DialogFlow. 
For some reason, the context is changed as it should, but only one time, and when I look at my logs, is see this error message.

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: [ResourceName error] Path '' does not match template 'projects/{project_id=*}/locations/{location_id=*}/agent/environments/{environment_id=*}/users/{user_id=*}/sessions/{session_id=*}/contexts/{context_id=*}'.
```

Here I will leave my code:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const { struct } = require('pb-util');
const credentials = {
    client_email: config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    private_key: config.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
};

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(
    {
        projectId: config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
        credentials
    }
);

const contextsClient = new dialogflow.ContextsClient(
    {
        projectId: config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
        credentials
    }
);
```

These are some consts and packages need for my code, and here is my code:

```
async function createContext(sender, contextId, parameters, lifespanCount = 1) {

    console.log("Sender antes: "+sender+" "+sessionIds.get(sender));

    if (!sessionIds.has(sender)) {
        sessionIds.set(sender, uuid.v1());
    }

    console.log("Sender despues: "+sender+" "+sessionIds.get(sender));

    const sessionPath = contextsClient.sessionPath(
                config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
                sessionIds.get(sender)
            );
    const contextPath = contextsClient.contextPath(
        config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
        sessionIds.get(sender),
        contextId
    );

    const request = {
        parent: sessionPath,
        context: {
            name: contextPath,
            parameters: struct.encode(parameters),
            lifespanCount
        }
    };

    const [context] = await contextsClient.createContext(request);

    return context;
}

function sendQuery(sender, query, context) {

    const session = sessionClient.sessionPath(
                config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
                sessionIds.get(sender)
            );

    const request = {
        session:session,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: query,
                languageCode: config.DF_LANGUAGE_CODE
            }
        },
        queryParams: {
            contexts: [context] // You can pass multiple contexts if you wish
        }
    };

    return sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
}
```

The second time I want to change the context the error change to this one:

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-06-06T12:31:33.177523+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

Comment: I have seen this on an entirely different area, I think its a GCP general error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit of a noob so take this with a grain of salt:

It looks like your connection request is failing (first error says path is ' ') which is causing the promise to reject, which is why the second error you included is complaining about using .catch(). Perhaps using that or a try/catch block would be useful to that end, but I *think* the root of the issue might be that the path used isn't correct.

Perhaps log out the URI you are attempting to request from to ensure the path matches

Comment: I am agree with your comment @stoneb, but which path is empty ? because both sessionclient and context cliente are here (I logged them): SessionPath: projects/cli*/agent/sessions/d*, 
ContextPath: projects/cli*/agent/sessions/d*/contexts/telefono